# Xcode How can I replace text with a hyperlink

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink

I am a newbie to Xcode so please bear with me.

I have a requirement where I have a some text on my view which is loaded from API call to server. ( in short dynamic text populated runtime).

Now I need to replace all @blabla and #blablabla to clickable links / buttons or anything else. It should be clickable and on click of it, should open another view.

Please suggest if I should elaborate a bit more on this.

Here is the use case to be more specific

1. View based application started
2. Application calls a webserver (API) and receives text paragraph.
3. It should show paragraph on screen but should replace @bla and @blabla with links and on click it should open another view ( not the webpage)

Answer (score 1):

The cheater method is to use an Open Source component. I've not used it, but [SMFancyText](https://github.com/simonmaddox/SMFancyText) might do the trick.